Is $(\partial_- X^{\mu},\partial_+ X^{\mu})$ an spinor on the world-sheet?
In the RNS string theory, the action is $$S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d^2 \sigma (\partial_{\alpha}X_{\mu}\partial^{\alpha}X^{\mu}+\bar{\psi}^{\mu}\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}\psi_{\mu})$$ where $X^{\mu}$ and $\psi^{\mu}$ are bosonic and fermionic fields, respectively. I have a question that arises from computing $\delta \bar{\psi^{\mu}}$ when $\delta \psi^{\mu}=\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}\epsilon$ considered in the supersymmetry. Dirac conjugate of a real spinor $\psi^{\mu}$ is defiend as $\bar{\psi}=\psi^{T}\beta$ where $\beta =i\rho^0$ and $\rho^0=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Considering $\psi=\begin{pmatrix}\psi_- \\ \psi_+\end{pmatrix}$, we have $\bar{\psi}=i(\psi_+,-\psi_-)$. Is the relation $\delta\bar{\psi}^{\mu}=\bar{\epsilon}\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}$ satisfied? From one hand, we have $\delta \bar{\psi}^{\mu}=i(2\partial_+ X^{\mu}\epsilon_-,2\partial_- X^{\mu}\epsilon_+)$ and from the other hand, we have $\bar{\epsilon}\rho^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}X^{\mu}=i(-2\epsilon_- \partial_+X^{\mu},-2\epsilon_+\partial_- X^{\mu})$. To have the equality, we must have $\epsilon_- \partial_+X^{\mu}=- \partial_+X^{\mu}\epsilon_-$ and $\epsilon_+ \partial_- X^{\mu}=- \partial_- X^{\mu}\epsilon_+$.  Is $(\partial_- X^{\mu},\partial_+ X^{\mu})$ an spinor on the world-sheet?
